# Transporting vectorized Matlab code to python, numpy

Tags: arrays, matlab, python-2.7, numpy, indexing

I am transporting my matlab code to python. There are alot of things that I am trying to find replacements for in python and numpy

Matlab Code:

```
    [m,n]=size(Image);

    canvas=zeros(m,n);

    U_res_sel=squeeze(loading);
    [s1,s2]=size(U_res_sel);

    if mod(s1,2)==0
        dy=s1/2-1;
    else
        dy=(s1-1)/2;
    end
    if mod(s2,2)==0
        dx=s2/2-1;
    else
        dx=(s2-1)/2;
    end

    xmin=dx+1;
    ymin=dy+1;
    xmax=n-(s2-dx-1);
    ymax=m-(s1-dy-1);

    [x,y]=meshgrid(xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax);

    ind=sub2ind([m,n],y(:),x(:));

    nps=repmat(((-dx+(0:s2-1))*m-dy),s1,1)+repmat((0:(s1-1)).',1,s2);

    ind=repmat(ind,1,numel(nps))+repmat(nps(:).',numel(ind),1);

    A=(Image(ind)-repmat(mean(Image(ind),2),1,numel(nps)));

    B=repmat((U_res_sel(:)-mean(U_res_sel(:))).',size(ind,1),1);

    canvas(ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax)=reshape(sum(A.*B,2)./sqrt(sum((A.^2),2).*sum((B.^2),2)),ymax-ymin+1,[]);

    canvas = canvas(y1+1:z1+y1+1,y2+1:z2+y2+1);
```

I guess i will explain line by line where problems are occurring.

i am using

import numpy as np

for the numpy functions

1.

The variables work fine until i reach the meshgrid line in python.

```
    [x,y] = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax]
```

x in matlab has a size 517,517 using test data
x in python has a size has 516 by 516 so i changed the python section of the code with

```
    xmax=n-(s2-dx-1) + 1
    ymax=m-(s1-dy-1) + 1

    [y,x] = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax]
```

to make it the same data sets as the matlab code. But I am not sure if the indexing is sound. If i have the exact same matrix in matlab to numpy array are they equivalent?

2.

The next matlab line is a mess for me to figure out.

```
    ind=sub2ind([m,n],y(:),x(:));
```

for the x(:) and y(:) i am using

```
    x = np.reshape(x,(x.size,1))
    y = np.reshape(y,(y.size,1))
    x = np.int64(x)
    y = np.int64(y)
```

for the sub2ind function i am using in python

```
    ind = np.ravel_multi_index((y,x), dims=(m,n) )
```

but here is where the numbers mess up.

in matlab i get a column vector with a range 3723 to 278760 for a certain data set
and for the same data set 
in python i get a column vector of 4264 to 279292 with a different stepping in between.

they both are the same size of (267289,1) though.

3.

This line i got working fine in matlab and python I am just putting it here so i can be concise to myself.

matlab:

```
    nps=repmat(((-dx+(0:s2-1))*m-dy),s1,1)+repmat((0:(s1-1)).',1,s2);
```

python:

```
    dtx = (-dx + np.arange(0,s2,1))
    dtx_2 = np.arange(0,s1,1)
    dtx_2 = np.reshape(dtx_2,(dtx_2.size,1))

    nps = np.tile(   dtx*m-dy,(s1,1)  ) + np.tile(   dtx_2  ,(1,s2)  )
```

(4).

for line in matlab

```
    ind=repmat(ind,1,numel(nps))+repmat(nps(:).',numel(ind),1);
```

in python i am trying

```
    a = np.tile(ind,(1,nps.size))
    b = np.tile( np.transpose(dtind) , (ind.size,1) )
    ind = a + b
```

I split it up into a and b to make it more readable.

But nothing in this is really working as intended.

(5).

I am unsure how to access a variable by index in python.

In matlab i could just do Image(ind), but is my code useless now in python because i can't find an alternative to this?

A bit of a note if you try running the matlab code, is that it will cause your computer and matlab to freeze and crash without warning if you run it on big data sets. I remedied this situation by by putting the code in a wrapper that indexes smaller portions of the data to get the final large image which prevents memory overflows.

I hope i made my mess of code clear enough. This code works fully well in matlab, but matlab is very terrible to be basing my projects in mainly because I can't give my code to other people.

EDIT:

This function is a vectorized program that basically does: (this is pseudocode so the indexing might not be right off the top of my head)

It also does not have padding in this segment. The loading variable i useis a gaussian matrix or a lapacian that can range from 6x6 to 64x64. It can be any size really, as long as its smaller than the image.

```
    correlation_coeficcient_surface = function(Image,loading)
    [m,n] = size(image)
    [u1,u2] = size(loading)
    canvas = zeros(size(image))
    for yii = 1:n
         for xii = 1:m
              image_segment = Image(yii-floor(u1/2):yii+ceil(u1/2),xii-floor(u2/2):xii+ceil(u2/2));
              if(size(image_segment) == size(loading)
                  canvas(yii-floor(u1/2):yii+ceil(u1/2),xii-floor(u2/2):xii+ceil(u2/2)) = corr2(Image_segment,loading);
              end
          end
     end


    end
```

It got to be vectorized because iterating over every element made it take really long amounts of time on large images.

Edit Edit:

Here is what my filter actually does.

This is a sample Image

http://i.imgur.com/o9kV3nK.png

This is a sample loading shape that i use to correlate with

http://i.imgur.com/oYW3k2K.png

this is after my matlab filter is finished the images are not aligned, i am just cropping examples to show you what it does shapewise.

http://i.imgur.com/aa4ljue.png

this is scipy.signal.convolve2d which does something that i am not intending.

http://i.imgur.com/vJhXMam.png

Comment: If you describe in code what your code is trying to do, it makes it a lot easier for others to read it and help you.

Comment: This looks like a 'sliding window' filter.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html The scipy ndimage package might apply.  numpy striding may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4947453/901925

Comment: I posted pictures of what my code actually does. If there is an existing filter that does it more efficiently than that would be more preferable. I could not find anything that did it in matlab though which made me to write my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to translating code from scratch using the tips in my other answer, this just looks like a convolution, and you could probably just use convolve2d (with zero padding here):

```
scipy.signal.convolve2d(Image, loading, mode='full', fillvalue=0.0)
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html if you want to do something more fancy than zero padding.

Edit: see [2D Convolution in Python similar to Matlab's conv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121269/2d-convolution-in-python-similar-to-matlabs-conv2) for more details on convolution

Edit 2 : The following code should calculate the local correlation coefficient over a sliding window. It should correctly handle the boundaries.

```
from scipy.signal import correlate2d
import numpy as np

# Generate random image
Image = np.random.rand(100,100)

# make kernel
x = np.arange(-10,11)
loading = np.exp( -(x[:,None]**2 + x[None,:]**2 )/10)


Image = np.tile(loading, (10,10))
m,n = loading.shape

oneskernel = np.ones(loading.shape)

# get number of points within each box of the sliding window
num = correlate2d(np.ones(Image.shape), oneskernel, mode='same')

# get mean over sliding window
Image_mu = correlate2d(Image, oneskernel, mode='same')/num

# Get sig of sliding window
Image_sig = np.sqrt(correlate2d((Image - Image_mu)**2,
                        oneskernel, mode='same')
                        / num)

loading_mu  =loading.mean() # mean of kernel
loading_sig = loading.std() # sig  of kenrel


# calculate sliding corrcoeff
C = correlate2d(( Image-Image_mu) / Image_sig , (loading -loading_mu)/loading_sig, mode='same') / num
```

Comment: I'm using corr2 not conv2, they do different operations.

Comment: ok, but correlation and convolution are quite similar operations, your original code can be done using conv2 type functions.

Comment: If i could use a function that is built in that does something mathematically similar, I am all for it. I posted images about what it does.

Comment: why don't you give the code I just added a try. it should calculate the local pearson corrceof over the sliding window.

Comment: This works a lot better than what I was using. I also don't have to deal with absurd amounts of memory requirements now. What also works better in python is that it handles the padding for me.

Comment: i'm glad. convolution is a tough operation to implement without using for loops. if you like this answer would you mind upvoting it?

Comment: Would if i had 15 reputation.

Comment: haha. just upvoted your question, should put you over the limit. btw i updated the code to normalize the means by the correct number of points near the boundaries.

Comment: Ah man thanks so much for the edge problem. I was having a bitch of a time trying to figure it out in python.

Comment: no problem. I would be interested to know what your dataset is

Comment: The data is from SEM and STM images.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should slow down a little, and read some materials about the basics of python arrays like indexing and broadcasting.  Firstly, I woud read the basic tutorial at http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/intro_numpy.html. Also http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html contains a table with correspondences between certain numpy and matlab operations. However, in general, I would keep an open mind and realize that the matlab-way is often not the best way in numpy.

I won't respond to all your questions directly, but here are the following thoughts.

1. Python indexing is zero indexed, . Therefore matlab `arr(1:100)` is the same as numpy `arr[0:100]`.
2. You can index numpy arrays with either logical arrays or arrays of indices like just like in matlab
3. In general, the functionality of `repmat` is handled in numpy by intelligent *broadcasting*, that doesn't require calling `tile` manually. For instance, the following code makes a random 100x100 array, calculates the row mean, and subtracts the row mean from the row (e.g. centers the data):

   ```
   arr = np.random.rand(100,100)
   mu  = arr.mean(axis=1)
   centered = arr - mu[:,None]
   ```

   The `mu[:,None]` array has size (100,1), and `numpy` is smart enough to "broadcast" it to size (100,100) to calculate `centered`. Continuing the example, `mu[:,None,None]` would have size (100,1,1).
4. Matlab's `size(arr)` is the same as numpy's `arr.shape`.

Good luck!

Edit: For instance you can do your #3 more concisely:

```
nps = (-dx+np.arange(s2)*m -du)[None,:] + np.arange(s1)[:,None]
```

And #4:

```
ind=  ind[:, None] + nps.ravel()[None, :]
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that in numpy, matlab's `array(sub2ind(size(array), x, y))` is expressed `array[x, y]`, and matlab's `array(x, y)` is expressed `array[np.ix_(x, y)]` (when x and y are both arrays).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `x` and `y` - the order of values is different, which you'll see if you try to flatten them:

```
x(:)'
1 1 ... 2 2 ....

x.flatten()
array([ 1,  2,  ... 10,  1,  2,...])
```

That is MATLAB arrays are arranged like 'F' numpy ones, not the default 'C'.

---

For small dimensions, I can match octave and numpy with:

```
"""
octave:47> [x,y]=meshgrid(1:3,3:4)
x =
   1   2   3
   1   2   3
y =
   3   3   3
   4   4   4
octave:48> ind=sub2ind([5,5],y,x)
    3    8   13
    4    9   14
"""
Y,X=np.mgrid[2:4,0:3]
"""
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
"""
ind = np.ravel_multi_index((X,Y),(5,5))
# np.ravel_multi_index((Y,X),(5,5),order='F')
"""
array([[ 2,  7, 12],
       [ 3,  8, 13]])
```

### """

I'm puzzled about the `Image(ind)` question.  `Image` is a [m,n] array, right?

Comment: Yes image is a m by n                                                             'K>> size(Image(ind))

ans =

      267289         256

K>> size(Image)

ans =

   532   532'